# Get Samsung KNOX api version on old devices like Jelly Bean

Tags: android, version, samsung-knox

I have a Samsung Galaxy Camera 2 with Android 4.3 Jelly Bean (it's about the same age as the Samsung Galaxy S3).

[Their docs](https://docs.samsungknox.com/dev/common/knox-version-mapping.htm) tells me, on Jelly Bean I can find KNOX Api level 5 - 10.

So, how do I find out which KNOX Api level I actually have?

- I couldn't find it in the system info page in the settings
- I haven't found a way to retrieve it [programmatically](https://docs.samsungknox.com/devref/knox-sdk/reference/com/samsung/android/knox/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Preferred method: Get API Level as int

The documentation on [EnterpriseDeviceManager.getAPILevel();](https://docs.samsungknox.com/devref/knox-sdk/reference/com/samsung/android/knox/EnterpriseDeviceManager.html#getAPILevel()) is wrong about the API level "Since: Knox API Level 24"!

[EnterpriseDeviceManager.getAPILevel();](https://docs.samsungknox.com/devref/knox-sdk/reference/com/samsung/android/knox/EnterpriseDeviceManager.html#getAPILevel()) **does actually work on old devices** like the Samsung Galaxy Camera NX with Android 4.2.2 (returns *7*) and Samsung Galaxy Camera 2 (returns *9*) when using the backward compatibility library of KNOX (Knox SDK Support Library for Old Namespace Translation)!

### Alternative method: Testing for methods

That's how we ended up testing for the KNOX Api level on old devices.

We looked for methods and classes in their documentation that only exist in certain API levels:

[image]

Comment: Nice. That was a detective job. You were lucky that there were actual API changes between releases and not only bug fixes.

Comment: Indeed ;) While coding the productive app we realized, it's not so much necessary to know the exact API level. We just check for the existance of the methods before using them.

Answer (score 2):

### Manually

#### Newer devices

Settings > About Device > Software Information > Knox Version

[image: software information menu]

#### Older devices

Find your device here: [Devices Secured by Knox](https://www.samsungknox.com/en/knox-platform/supported-devices)

### Programmatically

For API level 24 and higher you can retrieve the API level with [EnterpriseDeviceManager.getAPILevel()](https://docs.samsungknox.com/devref/knox-sdk/reference/com/samsung/android/knox/EnterpriseDeviceManager.html#getAPILevel()). It returns any of the constants defined in [EnterpriseDeviceManager.KNOX_VERSION_CODES](https://docs.samsungknox.com/devref/knox-sdk/reference/com/samsung/android/knox/EnterpriseDeviceManager.KNOX_VERSION_CODES.html).

With that integer value you can then go to the [reference table](https://docs.samsungknox.com/dev/common/knox-version-mapping.htm) and see more details.

Comment: It's Android 4.3. If I could read it in "Software information" I wouldn't ask that SO question. I definetely don't have API level 24.

Comment: I've edited the answer and added a link to a search page in Samsung's site where you can search by device name and model. Unfortunately your device (GC200) is more a camera than a phone, and it doesn't even show up there.

Comment: That list is garbage. It has no devices below Android 5.0. GC200 has KNOX support working but we want to determine the version. We also have the Samsung Galaxy S4 mini as development device which also doesn't appear in that list.